# Passing one model to another model as attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing an application on rails where you can access restaurants and make orders from the plates they offer. What I want to do now is that have created a scaffold for a shopping cart called "Cart" and I want to assign that to it when you create the order (which is also a scaffold).

It should be when you finish your shopping cart and press 'Continue Order' (views/cart/show.html.erb) which would redirect you to new_order_path where it asks you the other attributes of an other like the address, and payment method. I'm very confused as to when you can assign the cart you're in when you create the order.

Also, I already have this (on cart.rb):

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :order
```

And this on order.rb:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :cart
```

(UPDATE)I'm tying to assign the cart at the moment you submit the other parameters to complete an order on the form by doing this:

```
<%= form_with(model: order, local: true) do |form| %>
.
.
.
 <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit do order.asign(Cart.find(session[:cart_id])) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But it's not working

Comment: Can you share some more of your code? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Sure! I'm just kind of lost on what files would be useful, the controllers for cart and order? And about the errors it shows this `undefined method 'total_price' for nil:NilClass` for this line on the index of orders `<p>Total: <%= order.cart.total_price %></p>` which means the order is not receiving the cart

Comment: I've been trying to do it on the orders_controller by adding this: 
  
  `def show`
    `@order.cart = Cart.find(order_id: params[:id])`
  `end`
 but it's still not assigning the cart to the order

Answer (score 0):

In your `show.html.erb` file, change:

`<p>Total: <%= order.cart.total_price %></p>`

To:

`<p>Total: <%= @order.cart.total_price %></p>`

And in your `show` action in the `OrdersController` make it:

```rb
def show
  @order = Order.find(params[:id]) 
end
```

I've made the assumption you're passing the order ID under the `params[:id]`

You will continue to receive the error you are getting though until there is a valid `cart` object connected to the `order`.

To get around this, in `show.html.erb` you can do:

`<p>Total: <%= @order.cart.total_price || 0 %></p>`

And it will show the `total_price` as `0` if there isn't a `cart` associated with the `order`